# iTunes Backup - iOS & Settings only - No Apps

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

Is there a way to backup the iPhone such that none of the apps are included? I can always download the apps from the iTunes App Store after the iPhone is restored. I would like to backup all the settings for Mail, Messages, iCloud, and the OS itself .. but I just don't have enough space on my SSD for the App backups in iTunes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Back up to iCloud and to iTunes. Then, delete the `Mobile Applications` folder from Windows Explorer/Finder to remove the apps that have been backed up to iTunes.

### Long Answer

Make sure you read the [Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766) before you get started, but basically, I would recommend backing up to iCloud, which says that it will automatically back up your camera roll, accounts, documents, and settings. Then, do a full backup to iTunes by clicking `Back Up` when you plug in your iOS device. and you can remove the folder `Mobile Applications` on Windows or Mac by navigating to the `Users\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications` folder (actual folder names may vary based on operating system).

### Pictures

#### Deleting the Mobile Applications Folder

[image]
Look at the directory path at the bottom of the picture, too.